# Get JSON Value From a Script Tag

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, object

I'm trying to find a more efficient way to get the following JSON value. (Highlighted in yellow)
[image]

I currently use this code, which is ofcourse not very efficient but does the trick for now.

```
$("head > script:nth-child(55)").text().trim().replace("if(typeof dataLayer === 'undefined')", "").trim().replace("var dataLayer = [];", "").trim().replace("}", "").trim().replace("dataLayer.push({", "").replace(";", "")
```

Output:

```
                        'ecommerce': {
                            'detail': {
                                'actionField': {},
                                'products': [{
                                    'name': 'Monster Hunter Rise',         // Name or ID is required.
                                    'id': '5528442',
                                    'price': '59.98',
                                    'brand': 'New',
                                    'category': 'Software/Software/Standard',
                                    'variant': 'NoColour'
                                }]
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

I however, am looking for a more efficient way to do this. Which I am pretty sure there will be, but I can't find any solutions.

Comment: Please be aware that it is not JSON.

Comment: You should be able to access the `datalayer` array variable and just get `datalayer[0]` as an object

Answer (score 1):

As `dataLayer` is an `array` so you can use `index` to get the `ecommerce` object and use either `.` or `[]` to access property of an object which has a nester object `details` that contain `products` array.

So you need to access the first element(which is an object) of `products` array and get the `id` property of that object using `.` or `[]` notation.

```js
const dataLayer = [{
  ecommerce: {
    detail: {
      actionField: {},
      products: [{
        name: "Monster Hunter Rise", // Name or ID is required.
        id: "5528442",
        price: "59.98",
        brand: "New",
        category: "Software/Software/Standard",
        variant: "NoColour",
      }, ],
    },
  },
}, ];

const result = dataLayer[0].ecommerce.detail.products[0].id;
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is to display the value in HTML

```js
const dataLayer = [{
  ecommerce: {
    detail: {
      actionField: {},
      products: [{
        name: "Monster Hunter Rise", // Name or ID is required.
        id: "5528442",
        price: "59.98",
        brand: "New",
        category: "Software/Software/Standard",
        variant: "NoColour",
      }, ],
    },
  },
}, ];

var x = document.getElementById("displayval");
displayval.innerHTML = dataLayer[0].ecommerce.detail.products[0].id;
```

```html
<div id="displayval"></div>
```